# Implementing Semantic search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I want to implement semantic search  into my rails site.  I currently have a generic quick search.  I want the user to  be able to enter phrases and it returns the appropriate results rather  than user having to type a single word. Any gem for the same ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is a great java search engine based on lucene that has ruby clients.

http://rubygems.org/gems/rsolr

http://lucene.apache.org/solr

Although it might be overkill for a small site so it will depend on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sunspot, it is great https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot